# Do the elevators generate vortices?

Tags: aerodynamics

I want to know whether the elevators generate vortices like the wings do? If yes, then where do the vortices form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they do. The elevator vortices I have observed are pinned to the trailing edge corners of the elevator and are made visible when the aircraft is traveling through moist air that is very close to the dew point temperature, and at a significant angle of attack. There's a hotel at LAX where you can look out the windows and watch planes fly by on final, just before touchdown; on a foggy afternoon they are all trailing vortices behind them.

Comment: Proud Bird restaurant just down the road from LAX is another good place to watch from. On Aviation Blvd, very close to the landing ends of 24 L/R and 25 L/R.  Hilton at LAX also has a good view, especially from the upper rooms facing south. Farther away tho.  Too dry when I was there a month ago, no vortices seen.